# unloading a DLL until it's needed

Tags: vb.net, dll

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around some of the answers I've been reading here about unloading a plugin DLL using AppDomains. Here's my architecture:

In my solution, I have a `SharedObjects` project containing a `ModuleBase` class that all plugins (separate projects within the solution) inherit. In the `SharedObjects` project I also have an interface that all plugins implement (so if I have six plugins, they all implement the same interface and therefore the main program using these plugins doesn't need to know or even care what the name of the plugin's class was when it was compiled; they all implement the same interface and therefore expose the same information). Each plugin project has a project reference to the `SharedObjects` project. (As a side note, may be important, may not be - that `SharedObjects` project has a project reference to another solution, `CompanyObjects` containing a number of commonly-used classes, types, objects, etc.) When it's all said and done, when any given plugin compiles, the output directory contains the following DLLs:

1. The compiled DLL of the plugin itself
2. The DLL from the `SharedObjects` project
3. The DLL from the `CompanyObjects` project
4. Four prerequisite 3rd-party DLLs referenced in the `CompanyObjects` project

My main program creates a reference to the class where I'm doing all my plugin-related work (that class, `PluginHelpers`, is stored in the `SharedObjects` project). The program supplies an OpenFileDialog so that the user can choose a DLL file. Now, as it's running right now, I can move just the plugin DLLs to a separate folder and load them using the `Assembly.LoadFrom(PathToDLL)` statement. They load without error; I check to make sure they're implementing the interface in the `SharedObjects` project, gather some basic information, and initialize some background work in the plugin DLL itself so that the interface has something to expose. Problem is, I can't upgrade those DLLs without quitting the main program first because as soon as I use `LoadFrom` those DLLs are locked.

From [this MSDN site](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/a6a896ca-8905-41fb-8f52-7f39e89c9a91/) I found a solution to the problem of locked DLLs. But I'm getting the same "File or dependency not found" error as the OP using the code that worked for the OP. I even get the error when I open the DLL from the release folder which includes the rest of those DLLs.

The FusionLog is even more confusing: there's no mention of the path I was trying to open; it's trying to look in the directory where I'm debugging the main program from, which is a completely different project on a completely different path than the plugins, and the file it's looking for is the name of the DLL but in the folder where the program is running. At this point I have no idea why it's disregarding the path I gave it and looking for the DLL in a completely different folder.

For reference, here's my `Loader` class and the code I'm using to (try to) load the DLLs:

```
Private Class Loader
    Inherits MarshalByRefObject

    Private _assembly As [Assembly]
    Public ReadOnly Property TheAssembly As [Assembly]
        Get
            Return _assembly
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function InitializeLifetimeService() As Object
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Sub LoadAssembly(ByVal path As String)
        _assembly = Assembly.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path))
    End Sub

    Public Function GetAssembly(ByVal path As String) As Assembly
        Return Assembly.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path))    'this doesn't throw an error
    End Function
End Class

Public Sub Add2(ByVal PathToDll As String)
    Dim ad As AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TempPluginDomain")
    Dim l As Loader = ad.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
        GetType(Loader).Assembly.FullName,
        GetType(Loader).FullName
    )
    Dim theDll As Assembly = l.GetAssembly(PathToDll)    'error happens here
    'there's another way to do it that makes the exact point of the error clear:
    'Dim theDll As Assembly = Nothing
    'l.LoadAssembly(PathToDll)    'No problems here. The _assembly variable is successfully set
    'theDll = l.TheAssembly       'Here's where the error occurs, as soon as you try to read that _assembly variable.
    AppDomain.Unload(ad)
End Sub
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction so I can load and unload DLLs only as-needed and without any dependency errors?

Comment: You are creating an instance of *Loader* in the appdomain.  So now the Loader type is loaded both in the primary appdomain *and* the plugin appdomain.  You'll need an interface instead, declared in a separate assembly that can be loaded in both.  The plugin needs to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally got it. It ended up being a few things - I needed the shared DLLs all in one place, and as Hans mentioned above, I needed my appdomains squared away. My solution architecture looks like this: a folder with all my plugin projects; a "Shared Objects" assembly with one class file for the base plugin architecture, and a second class containing my "plugin wrapper" class and supporting classes; and a console app that ties everything together. Each plugin project has a project reference to the shared objects project, as does the console app. Nothing references the plugins directly.

So in my Shared Objects project, I have the code for my `PluginBase` class and my `IPlugin` interface:

```
Public Interface IPlugin
    ReadOnly Property Result As Integer
    Sub Calculate(ByVal param1 As Integer, ByVal param2 As Integer)
End Interface

Public MustInherit Class PluginBase
    Inherits MarshalByRefObject

    'None of this is necessary for the example to work, but I know I'll need to use an inherited base class later on so I threw it into the example now.

    Protected ReadOnly Property PluginName As String
        Get
            Return CustomAttributes("AssemblyPluginNameAttribute")
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected ReadOnly Property PluginGUID As String
        Get
            Return CustomAttributes("AssemblyPluginGUIDAttribute")
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected IsInitialized As Boolean = False
    Protected CustomAttributes As Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Protected Sub Initialize()
        CustomAttributes = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Dim attribs = Me.GetType.Assembly.GetCustomAttributesData
        For Each attrib In attribs
            Dim name As String = attrib.Constructor.DeclaringType.Name
            Dim value As String
            If attrib.ConstructorArguments.Count = 0 Then
                value = ""
            Else
                value = attrib.ConstructorArguments(0).ToString.Replace("""", "")
            End If
            CustomAttributes.Add(name, value)
        Next
        IsInitialized = True
    End Sub
End Class

<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)>
Public Class AssemblyPluginNameAttribute
    Inherits System.Attribute

    Private _name As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal value As String)
        _name = value
    End Sub

    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property PluginName As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)>
Public Class AssemblyPluginGUIDAttribute
    Inherits System.Attribute

    Private _g As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal value As String)
        _g = value
    End Sub

    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property PluginGUID As String
        Get
            Return _g
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

And I have my PluginWrapper class with its supporting classes:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection

''' <summary>
''' The wrapper for plugin-related activities.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks>Each wrapper contains: the plugin; code to load and unload it from memory; and the publicly-exposed name and GUID of the plugin.</remarks>
Public Class PluginWrapper

    Private _pluginAppDomain As AppDomain = Nothing
    Private _isActive As Boolean = False
    Private _plugin As IPlugin = Nothing
    Private _pluginInfo As PluginInfo = Nothing
    Private _pluginPath As String = ""

    Public ReadOnly Property IsActive As Boolean
        Get
            Return _isActive
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property PluginInterface As IPlugin
        Get
            Return _plugin
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property PluginGUID As String
        Get
            Return _pluginInfo.PluginGUID
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property PluginName As String
        Get
            Return _pluginInfo.PluginName
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal PathToPlugin As String)
        _pluginPath = PathToPlugin
    End Sub

    Public Sub Load()
        Dim l As New PluginLoader(_pluginPath)

        _pluginInfo = l.LoadPlugin()
        Dim setup As AppDomainSetup = New AppDomainSetup With {.ApplicationBase = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(_pluginPath).FullName}
        _pluginAppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(_pluginInfo.PluginName, Nothing, setup)
        _plugin = _pluginAppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(_pluginInfo.AssemblyName, _pluginInfo.TypeName)
        _isActive = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub Unload()
        If _isActive Then
            AppDomain.Unload(_pluginAppDomain)
            _plugin = Nothing
            _pluginAppDomain = Nothing
            _isActive = False
        End If
    End Sub

End Class

<Serializable()>
Public NotInheritable Class PluginInfo
    Private _assemblyname As String
    Public ReadOnly Property AssemblyName
        Get
            Return _assemblyname
        End Get
    End Property

    Private _typename As String
    Public ReadOnly Property TypeName
        Get
            Return _typename
        End Get
    End Property

    Private _pluginname As String
    Public ReadOnly Property PluginName As String
        Get
            Return _pluginname
        End Get
    End Property

    Private _pluginguid As String
    Public ReadOnly Property PluginGUID As String
        Get
            Return _pluginguid
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal AssemblyName As String, ByVal TypeName As String, ByVal PluginName As String, ByVal PluginGUID As String)
        _assemblyname = AssemblyName
        _typename = TypeName
        _pluginname = PluginName
        _pluginguid = PluginGUID
    End Sub
End Class

Public NotInheritable Class PluginLoader
    Inherits MarshalByRefObject

    Private _pluginBaseType As Type = Nothing
    Private _pathToPlugin As String = ""

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal PathToPlugin As String)
        _pathToPlugin = PathToPlugin
        Dim ioAssemblyFile As String = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(_pathToPlugin), GetType(PluginBase).Assembly.GetName.Name) & ".dll")
        Dim ioAssembly As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(ioAssemblyFile)
        _pluginBaseType = ioAssembly.GetType(GetType(PluginBase).FullName)
    End Sub

    Public Function LoadPlugin() As PluginInfo
        Dim domain As AppDomain = Nothing
        Try
            domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Discovery")
            Dim loader As PluginLoader = domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(GetType(PluginLoader).Assembly.FullName, GetType(PluginLoader).FullName)
            Return loader.Load(_pathToPlugin)
        Finally
            If Not IsNothing(domain) Then
                AppDomain.Unload(domain)
            End If
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Function Load(ByVal PathToPlugin As String) As PluginInfo
        Dim r As PluginInfo = Nothing
        Try
            Dim objAssembly As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(PathToPlugin)
            For Each objType As Type In objAssembly.GetTypes
                If Not ((objType.Attributes And TypeAttributes.Abstract) = TypeAttributes.Abstract) Then
                    If Not objType.GetInterface("SharedObjects.IPlugin") Is Nothing Then
                        Dim attribs = objAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(False)
                        Dim pluginGuid As String = ""
                        Dim pluginName As String = ""
                        For Each attrib In attribs
                            Dim name As String = attrib.GetType.ToString
                            If name = "SharedObjects.AssemblyPluginGUIDAttribute" Then
                                pluginGuid = CType(attrib, AssemblyPluginGUIDAttribute).PluginGUID.ToString
                            ElseIf name = "SharedObjects.AssemblyPluginNameAttribute" Then
                                pluginName = CType(attrib, AssemblyPluginNameAttribute).PluginName.ToString
                            End If

                            If (Not pluginGuid = "") And (Not pluginName = "") Then
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
                        r = New PluginInfo(objAssembly.FullName, objType.FullName, pluginName, pluginGuid)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Catch f As FileNotFoundException
            Throw f
        Catch ex As Exception
            'ignore non-valid dlls
        End Try

        Return r
    End Function
End Class
```

Finally, each plugin project looks a little like this:

```
Imports SharedObjects

<Assembly: AssemblyPluginName("Addition Plugin")> 
<Assembly: AssemblyPluginGUID("{4EC46939-BD74-4665-A46A-C99133D8B2D2}")> 

Public Class Plugin_Addition
    Inherits SharedObjects.PluginBase
    Implements SharedObjects.IPlugin

    Private _result As Integer

#Region "Implemented"
    Public Sub Calculate(ByVal param1 As Integer, ByVal param2 As Integer) Implements SharedObjects.IPlugin.Calculate
        If Not IsInitialized Then
            MyBase.Initialize()
        End If
        _result = param1 + param2
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Result As Integer Implements SharedObjects.IPlugin.Result
        Get
            Return _result
        End Get
    End Property
#End Region

End Class
```

To set it all up, the main program creates a new instance of the `PluginWrapper` class, supplies a path to a DLL, and loads it:

```
Dim additionPlugin As New PluginWrapper("C:\path\to\Plugins\Plugin_Addition.dll")
additionPlugin.Load()
```

Once you're done doing whatever you need to do with the program...

```
additionPlugin.PluginInterface.Calculate(3, 2)
```

...and retrieving the results...

```
Console.WriteLine("3 + 2 = {0}", additionPlugin.PluginInterface.Result)
```

...just unload the plugin:

```
additionPlugin.Unload()
```

If you need to reload it while the wrapper is still in memory, just call the `Load()` method again - all the information it needs to create a new AppDomain and reload the assembly is in there. And, in answer to my initial question, once the `Unload()` method has been called, the assembly is freed and can be replaced/upgraded as necessary, which was the whole point of doing this in the first place.

Part of where I was getting tripped up earlier was that I wasn't including the SharedObjects.dll file in the same folder as the plugins. What I found is that any referenced assembly needs to be present. So in my post-build events for both my plugins and the Shared Objects project, I have this: `xcopy /y $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)$(TargetFileName) c:\path\to\Plugins`. Every time I build the solution, all the DLLs are placed in the folder where they need to be.

Sorry if this is a little long, but this is a little complicated. Maybe there's a shorter way to do it...but at the moment, this gets me everything I need.